# Delegate submit handler for form in iframe loaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, iframe, onsubmit

Consider this example

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            function loadIframe()
            {
                $.get('echo_iframe.php', 
                    function(iframe) 
                    { 
                        $('#target').html(iframe); 
                    });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="target">
            <button onclick="loadIframe();">Load iFrame</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*echo_iframe.php:*

```
<?php
    echo '<iframe src="load_iframe.php" width="100%" height="150px"></iframe>';
```

*load_iframe.php:*

```
<?php
    echo
        '<form method="POST" action="form_action.php">
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>';
```

**Without changing any of the PHP or the *loadIframe* function,** is there a way to delegate an onsubmit event for the form using jQuery? Something like

```
$('body').on('submit', 'iframe form',
    function()
    {
        console.log('onsubmit');
    });
```

but actually works? The `submit` event doesn't bubble out of the `iframe`, and running an `$('iframe')` selector on page load won't work because the `iframe` won't be on the page yet.

I realize that I could just attach the event to the `iframe` at the same time that I create it in this example, but this is just a simplified example to convey the root of my problem more clearly. I am trying to abstract the concept to always delegate the same `onsubmit` event to any form that's within any `iframe` that is loaded via *AJAX*.